# How to access oracle sql from windows command line?

Tags: oracle

I have installed oracle (virtual box) on my laptop windows 7.

I can access sql plus command prompt once i logged in to virtul box.

Can i access the sql from windows command line ??

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed the Oracle client on a machine, then you can use sqlplus from that machine to connect to one or more Oracle instances on that same machine or on others.

Comment: I can connect to oracle from windows through sql developer. What i want is to connect through command prompt. I guess i have to put some environment variable or something .

Comment: SQL*Developer uses JDBC to connect; SQL*Plus uses OCI, and requires installation of the client.  Once installed and properly configured, one can open a command prompt and type `sqlplus`.

Comment: Thanks. I did a quick search to download sqlplus for window 7 But I did not get any link to download. Can you please paste any link from where i can download it?Thanks

Comment: you are looking for the Oracle Client - probably the same version as your database... (SQLPlus is included in that)

Comment: @ JavaOyeOye are you trying to access oracle installed in Virtual box in native os windows 7?